# Remove punctuations from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

I have this:

```
words = ["Alice's", 'Adventures', 'in', 'Wonderland', "ALICE'S", 'ADVENTURES', 'IN', 'WONDERLAND', 'Lewis', 'Carroll', 'THE', 'MILLENNIUM', 'FULCRUM', 'EDITION', '3.0', 'CHAPTER', 'I', 'Down', 'the', 'Rabbit-Hole', 'Alice', 'was']

remove_strings = str.maketrans('                           ', '!*01.23456,789-\,?\'\.(:;)\"!')

words = [s.translate(remove_strings) for s in words]
words = [words.lower() for words in words]
```

I want to get rid of all the punctuations and numbers.

But it just converts to lower case and does not remove the punctuations as I thought it would.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look into regex.

Comment: @Arpit have a look at module string - there are constants for digits and puntuation inside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.maketrans` maps characters specified in the first argument to the second argument, so you're really just mapping a space to a different character with your current code. A quick fix therefore is to simply swap the two arguments:

```
remove_strings = str.maketrans('!*01.23456,789-\,?\'\.(:;)\"!', '                           ')
```

An easier approach would be to use a regex substitution to replace all non-alphabets with a space:

```
import re

words = [re.sub('[^a-z]', ' ', word, flags=re.I).lower() for word in words]
```

Comment: Agree on your solution. But here, we have to list out all punctuations. I am sure a better way exist.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a simpler solution then.

Comment: This one replaces the punctuations but leaves no space. As a result- Alice's turns to Alices

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly then. Note that your wording of "remove" in the question makes it sound like you wanted to actually remove punctuations and numbers, rather than replacing them with spaces.

Comment: Thank You very much for your help. I will be more careful with the wordings next time. But looks like there is still some miss here. It is still replacing punctuations and not removing them.

Comment: You just said you wanted to turn `Alice's` into `Alice s` rather than `Alices`, and now you want to "remove" the punctuation again? What do you actually want to do to punctuations? If you want to replace them with spaces, my answer before the edit would do.

Comment: Thank You it does what you said. I had to restart kernel.

Comment: Yes, see [demo](https://tio.run/##TY8xb4MwEIV3foXFYpASVClLlwwIXGHJcSoC7RARyRSnseTa6EyK2j9PsbN0ufc@3fOdb/yZbtbsnkdYFvU1WpgQyCiaLQwO7dE5zrX6kNjFG4Tz4Vua6Q7S4ZWU8fXdmkGCFmZYKc4ZLQg@hXD5RnjT1uTkY5SH8JGXpGY5Lz0xOaswqRAAVmtvm4p4OVDGCOe0PXh6aVlRPywpaUOPYdguewqPq/y1IXVY4ktp5/Cx6Sa91KLv1bStrA74uGY1s3C4@3cnyMzd@wSfL2L72/kEWotvb9BVi0@3XxM0zbSdJSQpuloIXaRMUNdFIygzJQHSZfkD).